# The value for an attribute or a column are drawn from a set of values known as what?

Tags: rdbms

The value for an attribute or a column are drawn from a set of values known as what?
1) Tuples
2) Attributes
3) Domain
4) Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer out of four options is 3) Domain.

Answer (score 1):

attribute drawn from a set of values i.e domain (3. Domain - is the answer)

*if attributes drawn from atomic value domain called SIMPLE attributes.

- eg: name: {myName} , age : {23}

*if attributes drawn from set of value domain called MULTIVALUED attributes.

- eg: phone:{12334, 3242223, 234324}